# How can I color behind text in the console application?

Tags: c++, windows

How can I color behind text in a Windows 10 console application? (you can look at the picture as an example)

[image: console image]

Comment: That depends on what OS you're writing for.

Comment: And what terminal on that OS

Comment: Windows 10 @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute

Answer (score 0):

Use `WriteConsoleOutput`, see this for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput